# 'ST_Subdivide' function (3.5.0+ required) GEOS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geos, centos

Im running a query with ST_SubDivide() and receiving the error bellow.

```
ERROR:  The GEOS version this PostGIS binary was compiled against (34) doesn't support 'ST_Subdivide' function (3.5.0+ required)
```

Im on centOS7 with:

```
$ rpm -qa postg*
postgresql95-9.5.4-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgis2_95-client-2.2.2-3.rhel7.x86_64
postgresql-libs-9.2.15-1.el7_2.x86_64
postgresql95-libs-9.5.4-2PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
postgis2_95-2.2.2-3.rhel7.x86_64


$ rpm -qa geo*
geos-3.5.0-1.rhel7.x86_64
geos-devel-3.5.0-1.rhel7.x86_64
```

Question : How should i interpret this error of '**The GEOS version this PostGIS binary was compiled against (34)**' when on my view i have GEOS 3.5.0 installed , what are my options ?

Comment: compile postgis2 from source, using the desired version. or find a pre-compiled version that was compiled with the said version. 

if you need help on how to compile postgis2 in your system please refer at:
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/postgis_installation.html#PGInstall

Comment: Can you run the query: `select postgis_full_version();` and paste the results here?